# manipulate dynamic DOM with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dynamic table and would want it to only get focused when tabbing and not when clicking. I use MouseDown event, MouseUp event and Focus event to control it. Now the cell

```
<th tabIndex="0" 
    scope="col" 
    ref={this.myRef} 
    onMouseDown={this.testRef} 
    onMouseUp={this.testTwo} 
    onFocus={this.testThree}>Date</th>
```

works. However, I want every cell to have this kind of action without me manually needing to create so many ref and so on. How can I achieve that?

My code is as below:

```js
class App extends Component {
  
  state = {
    submissions: [
      {
        name: "cat",
        date: 12234,
        sourceLang: "en",
        targetLang: "to"
      },
      {
        name: "pig",
        date: 3456,
        sourceLang: "ko",
        targetLang: "op",
        files: [{ fileName: "piggy", type: "small" }]
      },
      {
        name: "fish",
        date: 3456,
        sourceLang: "ko",
        targetLang: "op"
      },
      {
        name: "dog",
        date: 3456,
        sourceLang: "ko",
        targetLang: "op",
        files: [
          { fileName: "doggy", type: "small" },
          { fileName: "puppy", type: "supersmall" }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "spider",
        date: 3456,
        sourceLang: "ko",
        targetLang: "op"
      }
    ],
    styleFocus: false,
    mouseDown: false
  };

  myRef = React.createRef();
  

  

  testRef = () => {
   
    this.setState({mouseDown: true})
    this.myRef.current.blur();
    console.log("testing", this.myRef.current);
  }

  testTwo = () => {
    console.log("testUp");
    this.myRef.current.blur();
   // if(this.state.mouseDown) {
     // this.myRef.current.blur()
  //  }
  }

  testThree = () => {
    console.log("testFocus");
    if(this.state.mouseDown) {
      this.myRef.current.blur()
    }
   // this.setState({mouseDown: false})
   else this.myRef.current.focus();
   this.setState({mouseDown:false})
  }

  handleFocus = () => {
    this.setState({ styleFocus: !this.state.styleFocus });
  };
  render() {
    const { name, date, sourceLang, targetLang } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <head>
          <h1>table</h1>
        </head>
        <body>
          <table
            className="focus"
            tabIndex="0"
            style={{ width: "80%" }}
            summary={"translated files row"}
          >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th tabIndex="0" scope="col">
                  FileOrFolder
                </th>
                <th tabIndex="0" scope="col" 
                  
                >
                  Name
                </th>
                <th tabIndex="0" scope="col"    ref={this.myRef} onMouseDown={this.testRef} onMouseUp={this.testTwo} onFocus={this.testThree} >
                  Date
                </th>
                <th tabIndex="0" scope="col"  >
                  Source language
                </th>
                <th tabIndex="0" scope="col" >
                  Target language
                </th>
                <th tabIndex="0" scope="col"  >
                  functionality
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.submissions.map((submission, i) => (
                <Rows
                  tabIndex="0"
                  key={i}
                  data={submission}
                  //name={name}
                  //date={date}
                  // sourceLang={sourceLang}
                  //targetLang={targetLang}
                />
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <hr />
          
          <MultiDropDown />
        </body>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want just to reuse these props?

```
tabIndex="0" 
scope="col" 
ref={this.myRef} 
onMouseDown={this.testRef} 
onMouseUp={this.testTwo} 
onFocus={this.testThree}
```

If yes, you could create an object with that and use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). For example:

```
const defaultProps = {
  onClick: () => console.log('cliked!'),
  styles: { color: 'red' }
}

<span {...defaultProps}>foo</span>
<span {...defaultProps}>bar</span>
```